# In HTML 5 ,i can't display the images in the browser through my code?

Tags: html

```
<HTML>

    <BODY style ="background-color:pink;">


    <H1 STYLE="margin-left:100px;"> AEROSPACE </HI>

    <h2>PHOTOS </h2>

    <img border="0" src="C:\Documents\baburaj.SIT.INDIA\Desktop\IMAGE\2.jpg" width="304" >
    </body>
</html>
```

i cannot display the images through my code given above.What change i have to do to display the image ?

Comment: which code? please provide some code what you tried so far.

Comment: <img border="0" src="C:\Documents and Settings\baburaj.SIT.INDIA\Desktop\IMAGE\2.jpg"width="304" height="228">

Comment: are you running your script on your desktop or on an webspace? maybe if you cut down `C:\Documents and Settings\baburaj.SIT.INDIA\Desktop\` assuming that your html file is on your desktop and change the backslash to a slash

Comment: Changing from backslah to slash means what ?

Comment: try <img border="0" src="IMAGE/2.jpg"width="304" height="228">

Comment: <HTML>
<BODY style ="background-color:pink;">
<H1 STYLE="margin-left:100px;"> AEROSPACE </HI>
<h2>PHOTOS </h2>
<img border="0" src="IMAGE/2.jpg" width="304" height="228">
</body>
<html>
Still not working ,QQping .

Comment: is your html file on your desktop or in the folder IMAGES?

Comment: The code is there, you just need to look hard enough. :)

Comment: No HTML file in folder called HTML CODES,AND this image folder is in the desktop .

Comment: @Daedalus if you edit this how are they supposed to learn asking proper questions? ^^

Comment: ok last try <img border="0" src="../IMAGE/2.jpg"width="304" height="228">

Comment: @QQping When i change my html file to desktop, it is working .So what is the problem if HTML file not in the desktop ?

Comment: Sometimes they do need to be shown; @BABURAJVD , next time when asking a question, add four spaces before your code blocks.  This will allow the code to be seen by others.

Comment: Oh thats great Deadalus, Thanks a lot for u r information

Comment: @QQping ,Ur replies was valuable.Now its working smoothly .Thanks a lot :)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Desktop
--HTML CODES
  --index.html
--IMAGES
  --2.jpg
```

I assume these are your current directories. If you call an image from `Desktop\HTML CODES` you have to provide a valid path.

For further reading refer to http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the image to same folder as the page so that instead of giving the full path of that image you can write 2.jpg

```
<img border="0" src="2.jpg" width="304" >
```

Also provide space between attributes.

Comment: What do u meant by same drive  ,sachin ?

Comment: <HTML>
<BODY style ="background-color:pink;">
<H1 STYLE="margin-left:100px;"> AEROSPACE </HI>
<h2>PHOTOS </h2>
<img border="0" src="IMAGE/2.jpg" width="304" height="228">
</body>
<html>